# How is the exception handled if you don't catch it?

Tags: java, exception

I am displaying countries and it's codes using `Locale.class`.

I just want to know How is the exception handled in the follwing code

```
 public Locale(String language, String country, String variant) {
    if (language== null || country == null || variant == null) {
        throw new NullPointerException();
    }
    baseLocale = BaseLocale.getInstance(convertOldISOCodes(language), "", country, variant);
    localeExtensions = getCompatibilityExtensions(language, "", country, variant);
}
```

as I'm not catching it in my class

```
String[] locales = Locale.getISOCountries();

    for (String countryCode : locales) {

        Locale obj = new Locale("", countryCode); //NullPointerException - thrown if either argument is null. 

        System.out.println("Country Code = " + obj.getCountry()
                + ", Country Name : " + obj.getDisplayCountry());

    }
```

As I know the method has to use `throws` to throw any new `Thowable` object and the newly throwned object must be handled in the implemented class.

I'm a Newbie with exception handling in java.

Comment: a new `NullPointerException` instance is thrown only if the condition `language== null || country == null || variant == null` is satisfied.

Comment: NullPointerException is not a checked exception, so it does not need to be declared nor handled.

Comment: Sincerely your question is not clear. What does it mean `I just want to know how the throw new NullPointerException(); in the follwing code`?

Comment: @nbro I mean to say that, how the thrown exception is handled as I'm not catching it in my class.

Comment: Q: How is the exception handled if you don't catch it? A: It's not handled. ;-)

Comment: @The111 : Thanks a lot for the Q: and A: and that's exactly what in my question is.

Comment: As Elliott Frisch mentions in his answer, if you don't handle it, the JVM will "handle" it by terminating.  If you run your code you'll see this happen.

Comment: Thanks for all the responses. Now I'm clear that "NullPointerException is not a checked exception, so it does not need to be declared nor handled" as @Jeffrey Bosboom stated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Per the [`NullPointerException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/NullPointerException.html) Javadoc, it extends `RuntimeException`. And per the [`RuntimeException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/RuntimeException.html) Javadoc,

> `RuntimeException` and its subclasses are *unchecked exceptions*. Unchecked exceptions do not need to be declared in a method or constructor's throws clause if they can be thrown by the execution of the method or constructor and propagate outside the method or constructor boundary.

In your example, if you trigger that `NullPointerException` your JVM will terminate and display a stack trace.

Comment: Strictly speaking, the thread will terminate with a stack trace (from the default uncaught exception handler); the JVM itself will only terminate if that was the last non-daemon thread in the JVM.